# Storing Carrierwave as json into an existing jsonb column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

I'm not sure if this is even possible using Carrierwave, I'm still learning my way around Ruby and Rails so bear with me.

I have a simple form to record observations. Each observation has data that can be recorded against it and I store this in a JSONB column within the observation (I will eventually store multiple sets of data against an observation). I want to be able to upload an image through Carrierwave and store it with the data within the JSONB column rather than saving it to its own column. So my saved data for this column would be like this for example...

```
{  
   "ph":"",
   "ecoli":"",
   "nitri":"Less than 0.5",
   "oxygen":"",
   "clarity":"bottom visible",
   "nitrates":"Less than 0.5",
   "conditions":[  
      "Wildlife Death",
      "Shoreline Alterations",
      "Water Quality"
   ],
   "observed_on":"2015-06-21T04:45",
   "invasive_species":[  
      "Phragmites",
      "Loosestrife",
      "Dog-Strangling Vine"
   ],
   "phosphates_threshold":"less than 0.2",
   "image":[  
      "url": "the/url",
      "thumbnail: "the/thumbnail/url",
      "medium":"the/thumbnail/url"
      .....
   ]
}
```

Some of the supporting code for reference...

*observation.rb*

```
class Observation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments
  serialize :observation_data, HashSerializer
  store_accessor :observation_data
end
```

*observation_data.rb - tableless model*

```
class ObservationData < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :observation
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

*_form.html.erb*

```
<%= form_for @observation do |f| -%>
  ...Other form items
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Observation data</legend>
    <%= render "observation_data", :f => f %>
  </fieldset>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "button" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

*_observation_data.html.erb*

```
<%= f.fields_for :observation_data, OpenStruct.new(@observation.observation_data)  do |o| %>
  ...Other form items
  <div class="field">
    <%= o.label :image, "Upload an image" %>
    <%= o.file_field :image %>
  </div>
  ...Other form items
<% end %>
```

*observations_controller.rb*

```
class ObservationsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_observation, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def index
    @observations = Observation.all
    @user = current_user.id
  end

  def show
    @observations = Observation.find_by(id: params[:id])
    @observation_data = @observation.observation_data
    @comments = @observation.comments.all
    @comment = @observation.comments.build
    @user = User.find_by(id: @observation.user_id)
  end

  def new
    @observation = Observation.new 
  end

  def edit

  end

  def create
    @observation = Observation.new(observation_params)
    @observation.user_id = current_user.id
    respond_to do |format|
      if @observation.save
        format.html { redirect_to @observation, notice: 'Observation was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @idea }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @observation.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @observation.update(observation_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @observation, notice: 'Observation was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @observation.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @observation.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to root_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private

    def set_observation
      @observation = Observation.find(params[:id])
    end

    def observation_params
      params.require(:observation).permit(:user_id, :lat, :lng, :name, :description, :comment, observation_data: [:observed_on, :image, :ph, :oxygen, :ecoli, :phosphates_threshold, :clarity, :nitri, :nitrates, wildlife: [], conditions: [], invasive_species: []])
    end

end
```

The problem for me is `mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader` is always looking for an `:image` column, how can I merge the Carrierwave response this with JSON in another column? Is it even possible?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Looking for a solution myself.

Comment: @EricM. We ended up taking a different route in the end (changing our data structure due to other factors). I've still not discovered a way to do this!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it, so this is how I created a wrapper for the `store` option with some tricky overrides based on [their suggestions](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/1531a67366f0e25e3d298133a72c81b6c9c0dc83/lib/carrierwave/mount.rb#L450-L458). In your case can be simplified to the main image key inside the JSON object and complement with the other data as additional. Because this one is intended to be more open and all of them for images.

This is the example:

### Migration

```rb
  # Set the column accordingly to your need like observation_data
  t.jsonb :images
```

### Model

```rb
class Campaign < ApplicationRecord
  AVAILABLE_IMAGES = %i[
    home_desktop_img
    home_mobile_img
    srp_desktop_img
    srp_mobile_img
    money_desktop_img
    money_mobile_img
  ].freeze

  store :images, accessors: AVAILABLE_IMAGES, coder: JSON

  AVAILABLE_IMAGES.each do |image_type|
    # General image method change based on store
    define_method(:"#{image_type}_will_change!") { images_will_change! }
    mount_uploader image_type, CampaignImageUploader
  end

  def read_uploader(column)
    column_sym = column.to_sym
    if AVAILABLE_IMAGES.include? column_sym
      read_store_attribute(:images, column_sym)
    else
      super(column)
    end
  end

  def write_uploader(column, identifier)
    column_sym = column.to_sym
    if AVAILABLE_IMAGES.include? column_sym
      write_store_attribute(:images, column_sym, identifier)
    else
      super(column, identifier)
    end
  end
end
```